# Using subquery in join clause instead of column name

Tags: sql, join, subquery, greenplum

I am trying to join a two table. One column exists in the table but the other is a derived one.

```
event_date - exists directly in the table
deploy_date - derived using case statement
```

See line #6 in the original query.

```
   1 SELECT    ab.id, 
   2          ab.event_date, 
   3           CASE 
   4                     WHEN ab.label = 'ABC' THEN ab.event_date 
   5                     WHEN ab.label = 'DEF' THEN ab.start_date 
   6           END deploy_date, 
   7 FROM      ab_bro AB 
   8  LEFT JOIN ab_rev rv 
   9 ON        ab.bro_id = rv.bro_id 
   10 AND       ab.event_date = rv.event_date
```

Now I want to use `deploy_date` instead of `event_date` in line #10 (above)
Since sql doesn't allow alias to be used in joins, I tried to use subquery

```
SELECT    ab.id, 
          ab.event_date, 
          CASE 
                    WHEN ab.label = 'ABC' THEN ab.event_date 
                    WHEN ab.label = 'DEF' THEN ab.start_date 
          END deploy_date, 
FROM      ab_bro AB 
LEFT JOIN ab_rev rv 
ON        ab.bro_id = rv.bro_id 
AND 
          ( 
             SELECT 
                 CASE 
                     WHEN AC.label = 'ABC' THEN AC.event_date 
                     WHEN AC.label = 'DEF' THEN AC.start_date 
                  END deploy_date from ab_bro AC) = rv.event_date
```

My error -

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I understand that my subquery is indeed returning more than one row but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: This seems very odd.  If you remove the `SELECT` before the `CASE`, do you still get the same error?

Comment: @GordonLinoff that is leading to syntax error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is Greenplum. I fixed the tag. Since GP is based on top of Postgres, I assumed it would have similar syntax

Comment: @PirateX Remove the `from ab_bro AC` as well as the `SELECT` there is no need for the subquery, just the CASE expression.

Comment: @JNevill turns out I was missing the END of case statement. I think I need some rest. Thanks a bunch !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do here is use that CASE expression in your JOIN criteria:

```
SELECT
    ab.id,
    ab.event_date,
    CASE
        WHEN ab.label = 'ABC'
            THEN ab.event_date
        WHEN ab.label = 'DEF'
            THEN ab.start_date
    END deploy_date,
FROM ab_bro AB
    LEFT JOIN ab_rev rv
        ON ab.bro_id = rv.bro_id 
        AND rv.event_date = CASE
                WHEN ab.label = 'ABC'
                    THEN ab.event_date
                WHEN ab.label = 'DEF'
                    THEN ab.start_date
                END
```

Answer (score 0):

If the AND ( ) subselect retunr more then  rows  you could use limit1

```
SELECT    ab.id, 
          ab.event_date, 
          CASE 
                    WHEN ab.label = 'ABC' THEN ab.event_date 
                    WHEN ab.label = 'DEF' THEN ab.start_date 
          END deploy_date, 
FROM      ab_bro AB 
LEFT JOIN ab_rev rv 
ON        ab.bro_id = rv.bro_id 
AND   ( 
             SELECT 
                 CASE 
                     WHEN AC.label = 'ABC' THEN AC.event_date 
                     WHEN AC.label = 'DEF' THEN AC.start_date   
                  END deploy_date from ab_bro AC
                  limit 1 ) = rv.event_date
```

or use IN instead of =

```
  SELECT    ab.id, 
          ab.event_date, 
          CASE 
                    WHEN ab.label = 'ABC' THEN ab.event_date 
                    WHEN ab.label = 'DEF' THEN ab.start_date 
          END deploy_date, 
FROM      ab_bro AB 
LEFT JOIN ab_rev rv 
ON        ab.bro_id = rv.bro_id 
AND  rv.event_date IN  ( 
             SELECT 
                 CASE 
                     WHEN AC.label = 'ABC' THEN AC.event_date 
                     WHEN AC.label = 'DEF' THEN AC.start_date   
                  END deploy_date from ab_bro AC
                  limit 1 )
```

Comment: I can use limit clause but I think it would impact on the logic. Any idea on that ?

Comment: I don't know your logic goal ..anyway   using limit you should add  an order by for control the value return  ..

Comment: Yea, I tried it. it is messing with the logic. Thanks anyway! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It would at least be a little more tidy to join an inline view instead of putting a `CASE` statement in your `WHERE` clause.  That will allow you to avoid duplicating the `CASE` expression.  Some might consider it cleaner and clearer still to use a CTE instead of an inline view:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    bro_id,
    event_date,
    CASE label
      WHEN 'ABC' THEN event_date 
      WHEN 'DEF' THEN start_date 
    END deploy_date
  FROM ab_bro
)
SELECT
  x.id, 
  x.event_date, 
  x.deploy_date
FROM
  x
  LEFT JOIN ab_rev rv 
    ON x.bro_id = rv.bro_id 
      AND x.deploy_date = rv.event_date
```

You can think of both of those variants as creating a temporary table containing the derived data as an ordinary column, and joining that to the other table.

Comment: The snippet I shared in my post is actually a very small piece of a huge sql code and moving entire logic to CTE may result in over complication (for me atleast)

Comment: @PirateX It may seem to be over-complication, but sometimes breaking a query out into pieces logic can help get the correct answer your need. I'm not familiar with Greenplum, but if you want to use `deploy_date`, it has to exist before the `JOIN`. Since `FROM` and `JOIN` usually happens early in the logical query process, your alias column needs to exist, necessitating a CTE or a subquery.

Comment: It's your code, @PirateX.  From my perspective, though, using a CTE is *simpler*, not to mention more maintainable, than putting the `CASE` in your where clause.  But note that it is *not* putting the entire logic into a CTE (or inline view).  It is putting the generation of synthetic columns into the CTE.  If it's naming all the individual columns that bothers you, then you ought to be able to abbreviate the whole list of existing columns to just `*`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the input. I'll definitely try to inculcate those points :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sub.id,
    sub.event_date,
    sub.deploy_date
FROM (
    SELECT ab.id, 
        ab.event_date, 
        ab.bro_id,
        CASE 
            WHEN ab.label = 'ABC' THEN ab.event_date 
            WHEN ab.label = 'DEF' THEN ab.start_date END as deploy_date, 
    FROM ab_bro AB 
    ) AS sub
LEFT JOIN ab_rev rv ON sub.bro_id = rv.bro_id 
AND sub.deploy_date = rv.event_date;
```